# byte.parse() doesn't like 8 bit

Tags: java, byte

This code

```
byte b = Byte.parseByte("10000000", 2);
```

throws an exception in Java. This should be -128 or 255.

Byte has 8 bit. Why can't I parse a 8 bit string?

Comment: For Java the maximum value is (2^(8-1)) - 1 = 127 because it uses two's complement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is down to the range of a `byte` in Java.  Bytes are **signed**, so you can have anything from -128 (`"-10000000"`) through to 127 (`"1111111"`), but no values outside that range.

Answer (score 2):

The MAX_VALUE of a byte in java (or in C#) is 127 where as 10000000 return 128 which cannot be stored in a byte variable

Comment: Actually in C# it's 255; C# bytes are unsigned.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do treat the value as signed this way.

```
byte b = (byte) Integer.parseInt("10000000", 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly, you passed not eight bits to `parse` method, but string representation of usual number with radix 2. And it may contain a sign character. Particularly, `byte b = Byte.parseByte("-10000000", 2)` works nice and gives -128.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an 8-bit string, it's an 8-character string, and it's not being read the way you think it is...

From the MSDN documentation ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0s9b1y3.aspx)), you'll see that `byte.Parse` accepts strings in the integer format.  So, you're trying to parse 10 million, not -1.  The exception you're getting gives this away: you should see an `OverflowException`.

`byte.parse("255")` gives the effect you expect (`byte` is unsigned; using -128 also gives an overflow).

Comment: *sigh*... Original question was posted in Java and C#.